# Can you use multiple client/lib/server folders with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Reason i ask is i like to seperate my projects up into components and with Meteor i'm guessing that would mean somethings along the lines of:

```
└── app
    └── apps
        ├── .meteor
        ├── blog
        │  ├── client
        │  ├── lib
        │  └── server
        ├── faqs
        │  ├── client
        │  ├── lib
        │  └── server
        └── people
            ├── client
            ├── lib
            └── server
```

Or is my only option to do this:

```
└── app
    ├── .meteor
    ├── client
    │  └── apps
    │      ├── block
    │      ├── faqs
    │      └── people
    ├── lib
    │  └── apps
    │      ├── block
    │      ├── faqs
    │      └── people
    └── server
       └── apps
           ├── block
           ├── faqs
           └── people
```

Comment: consider looking into the "package-only" approach. that's the meteor way of doing what you wanna do.

Comment: Wasn't aware of this, will have a look into it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Official doucmentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) you can see the differents way to structure your app.

**Method 1: Root-Level Folders**

```
apples/lib/               # code for apple-related features
apples/client/
apples/server/

oranges/lib/              # code for orange-related features
oranges/client/
oranges/server/
```

**Method 2: Folders inside client/ and server/**

```
lib/apples/               # common code for apples
lib/oranges/              # and oranges

client/apples/            # client code for apples
client/oranges/           # and oranges

server/apples/            # server code for apples
server/oranges/           # and oranges
```

**Method 3: Packages**
This is the ultimate in code separation, modularity, and reusability. If you put the code for each feature in a separate package, the code for one feature won't be able to access the code for the other feature except through exports, making every dependency explicit. This also allows for the easiest independent testing of features. You can also publish the packages and use them in multiple apps with meteor add.

```
packages/apples/package.js     # files, dependencies, exports for apple feature
packages/apples/<anything>.js  # file loading is controlled by package.js

packages/oranges/package.js    # files, dependencies, exports for orange feature
packages/oranges/<anything>.js # file loading is controlled by package.js
```

Answer (score 1):

The top one you listed is perfectly valid. The bottom one makes no sense (putting a `client` folder within a `server` folder). So yes, you could structure your application in that way, though many people would recommend separating out the features of your app into separate packages.

Comment: Sorry, the 2nd one was a typo, i've edited it now to reflect what i actually meant

Comment: JuanCrg90's answer wins. :)